# Start Android Wifi Settings - restricted

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, android-wifi

Is there a way to open the Android Wifi Settings and restrict access to just wifi settings?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above will open the android settings to the wifi fragment, but the user can touch the Setting button in the upper left corner and then have access to all settings.

I do not want the user to have access to all the setting, just the wifi settings.

Target is API 19 (KitKat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  What you're doing with that code is starting an Activity that will display and do whatever it wants-  it just claims its allowed to pick a wifi network.  There's no way to effect what else that activity displays unless they have an intent extra that configures it, and this one doesn't.  Even if you found one it would be unlikely to work across all devices as OEMs frequently customize these activities.